# Subiquity - Dual Boot Storage Setup

Tags: dual-boot, subiquity, user-data, autoinstall

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 22 via Subiquity alongside a Windows install on 1 disk? And if so, how is the `user-data` file configured? In pre-seed, I could use the following:

```
d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select biggest_free
```

But i cannot find an equivalent command for `autoinstall`.